# Touchpad not working/detected on 14.04 also error while startup booting

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I recently updated my Dell 15 laptop from 12.04 to 14.04.. but now I am facing problem while starting up. It types some texts on blacks screen saying *^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^\^..* on and on.. and **does not show me options for selection for memory test and other options that generally come. After logging in find touch-pad not responding/ detected** but an external mouse works fine. I Have only one OS in my system which came with pre-installed 12.04

Please suggest a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver package:

```
sudo apt-get install xsrver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

If it is already installed, then reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xsrver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xsrver-xorg-input-synaptics
```